# About matlab quadprog using a structure hessian

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, quadratic

I've been using matlab for solving a quadratic optimization problem, using a factor structured hessian, say I have a covariance matrix H and I wrote it as H=A+B*B'.

Then I have a small piece of code to calculate the

`hessianf=@f;
options = optimset('HessMult', hessianf);

y1 = quadprog(A, r, [], [], [], [], [], [], [], options, B);`

with

`function H=f(A,x,B)
H=A*x+B*(B'*x);
end`

The above process is just following http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brn4nlc.html

However, matlab says "H must be specified explicitly for the active-set algorithm: cannot use HessMult option.".

I got very confused at where the problem is. Could anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `trust-region-reflective` algorithm instead of `active-set`. So add `optimset('Algorithm', 'trust-region-reflective')` to your options.